Библиотеки для изображений в Си
Подскажите, пожалуйста, какие-нибудь библиотеки с функциями сравнение и перевода в негатив  2 бмп изображений. Или подскажите, пожалуйста, варианты самостоятельной реализации этого кодом, если таких готовых функций нет.

Есть такая известная программа, написанная на Си -- GIMP, которая использует библиотеку GEGL. Если бы передо мной серьезно  встала задача обработки изображений, то я бы в первую очередь ознакомился с их сорсами (думаю, нашел бы где-нибудь на github)

Кстати, если полазить по ссылкам из статьи про GIMP, то легко обнаруживается масса и других библиотек для обработки изображений, написанных на Си
